# Modify bash arguments if only one argument is set

Tags: bash, arguments

I created a [script](https://github.com/ffnord/batman-connect/blob/bd424aef562e6e20c555d0d39186d212f7e54450/batman-connect) with the standard [`getopt` magic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140691/default-argument-parsing-section), so you can call the script with

```
batman-connect -c ffki
```

How can I add an option to call this script with only one option without dash?

```
batman-connect ffki
```

so It will interpret this only option as the second argument for `-c`?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827707/1069083) I tried:

```
if [ $@ = "ffki" ]; then
  set -- "-c $@"
fi
```

But that gives an error, I think because this line in my [script](https://github.com/ffnord/batman-connect/blob/bd424aef562e6e20c555d0d39186d212f7e54450/batman-connect) will change it back:

```
# Execute getopt on the arguments passed to this program, identified by the special character $@
PARSED_OPTIONS=$(getopt -n "$0"  -o hsrvVi:c: --long "help,start,restart,stop,verbose,vv,version,interface:,community:"  -- "$@")
```

I don't like to re-arrange my whole script, so is there a simple one-liner to just set the first argument to "-c" and the second to "ffki" ?

Comment: You were *very* close, as Gilles ultimately explains in his 21-line answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
if [ $# = 1 ]; then
    # do whatever you'd do when there is only one argument
else
    # do the getopt bits
fi
# do what you'd do in either case
```

If -c is the only switch you want to support, then you don't need getopt and can instead do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [ -c ] arg" >&2
    exit 1
}

if [ $# = 2 ]; then
    if [ $1 = "-c" ]; then
        shift
        c_switch_value="$1"
    else
        usage
    fi
elif [ $# = 1 ]; then
    c_switch_value="$1"
else
    usage
fi
```

Whether this is more readable is debatable though.

Comment: But then I would have to rearrange my whole script. Isnt there a way to just set the forst argument to "-c" and the second to "ffki" then?

Answer (score 1):

I added right at the beginning of this script:

```
if [ $# = 1 ]; then
  # If there is only one argument, replace the current process with the new invocation of the script
  # the only option will be used as -c option
  exec "$0" -c "$@"
fi
```

This doesn't answer the initial question, but it a workaround, that works in my special case.

Comment: That's a good place for `exec`: `exec "$0" -c "$@"` -- don't forget to quote `"$@"`

Comment: Thx, I added quotes. Why `exec`?

Comment: It will *replace* the current process with the new invocation of the script. Save the shell from having to create a new process. Also avoids the need to call exit.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if [ $@ = "ffki" ]; then
> ```

The command in the `if` clause expands to `[` followed by the list of wildcard expansions of the words that make up the positional parameters followeb by the words `=` `ffki` `]`. Generally speaking, `$VAR` does not mean “the value of `VAR`” when it's outside double quotes, it means “split the value of `VAR` into separate words and interpret them as globs”. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Furthermore `"$@"` is a special case: it expands to the list of positional parameters (without further expansion), not to a single word (despite the quotes). You can use `"$*"`, which expands to a single word made up of the positional parameters separated by a space (more precisely, by the first character of the value of `IFS`). So to test whether there is a single positional parameter whose value is `ffki`, you can use

```
if [ "$*" = "ffki" ]; then
```

Alternatively, you can count the number of positional parameters and test their value individually. This would be necessary if you wanted to allow values containing spaces, for example.

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = "ffki" ]; then
```

To change the positional parameters, you were close: use the `set` builtin, and pass the new set of positional parameters as separate arguments. If there's a risk that the first parameter begins with a `-`, use `set -- …` so that it isn't interpreted as an option.

```
if [ "$*" = "ffki" ]; then
  set -- -c "ffki"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
# getopt code that sets "$c_value" goes here ...
# ... then
if [[ -z $c_value ]] && (( $# > 0 )); then
    c_value=$1
    shift
fi
```

Comment: will this get past my line `PARSED_OPTIONS` in my [script](https://github.com/ffnord/batman-connect/blob/bd424aef562e6e20c555d0d39186d212f7e54450/batman-connect)?

Comment: try it and see.